# Two postgresql tables referencing each other

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, relationship

Question may be basic, I don't have any experience with databases.

I have a postgres db with some tables. Two of them are `dates` and `accounts`.

The `date` table has an `account_id` field referencing an `id` table in  an `account` table and a `balance` field that represents the balance that account had at that date. So, many `date` entities may reference one `account` entity, many-to-one, okay.

But an `account` table also has an `actual_date` field, that must reference the `date` entity, with actual balance this account has. One `account` entity may reference one actual `date` entuty, but `date` entity can have one or zero `account` entities referncing it. And if it does have an account referencing it with it's `actual_date`, it will always be the same account, `date` itself referencing with `account_id`.

What kind of relathinship is this? Is it even possible to implement? And if it is, how do I do it?

[image]

I came up with this piece of code, but I have no clue if it does what I think it does.

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT REFERENCES users,
    actual_date_id DATE UNIQUE REFERENCES dates
);
CREATE TABLE dates (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    account_id INT REFERENCES accounts,
    date DATE,
    balance INT,
    unconfirmed_balance INT
);
```

P.S. I create tables with init.sql but work with them with sqlalchemy and it would be greate if someone could also show how to define such model with it.

Comment: What does this statement actually mean: "date entity can have one or zero account entities referencing it"? What would a record in this table without an account entity represent?

Comment: Record in dates table would keep a balance a certain account had at a certain day. Also, there is other tables. Events table references dates so I can keep track of when events occur and which events happen at certain date

Comment: Using the same table (dates) to hold information about 2 different entities (balances and events) doesn't seem like a good design decision to me. Why not replace the "dates" table with an "account balances" table (and you can include a flag for the current balance for each account if you want) and just add a date attribute to your events?

Comment: I thought that there may be days without transactions on certain accounts and searching events by days may be more efficient, than searching among all events ever. But I may be wrong, as I said, I have no expirience with databases. Why is it a bad design?

Comment: Also, I've already used flag is_current_balance as a_horse_with_no_name advised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written the SQL script would never work for two reasons:

1. a foreign key can only reference the *primary key* of a table, not any arbitrary column in it. So actual_date_id should be an `integer` in order to be able to reference the primary key of the `dates` table.
2. you can't reference a table that hasn't been created yet, so the foreign key between accounts and dates must be created after both tables are created.

With circular foreign keys it's usually easier to define at least one of them as deferrable, so that you can insert them without the need of e.g. an intermediate NULL value.

So something along the lines (assuming that `users` already exists)

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT REFERENCES users,
    actual_date_id integer UNIQUE -- note the data type
);

CREATE TABLE dates (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    account_id INT REFERENCES accounts,
    date DATE,
    balance INT,
    unconfirmed_balance INT
);

-- now we can add the foreign key from accounts to dates
alter table accounts
  add foreign key (actual_date_id)
  references dates (id)
  deferrable initially deferred;
```

---

It might be better to avoid the circular reference to begin with. As you want to make sure that only one "current balance" exists for each account, this could be achieved by adding a flag in the dates table and getting rid of the `actual_date_id` in the accounts table.

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT REFERENCES users
);

CREATE TABLE dates (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    account_id INT REFERENCES accounts,
    is_current_balance boolean not null default false,
    date DATE,
    balance INT,
    unconfirmed_balance INT
);

-- this ensures that there is exactly one row with "is_current_balance = true" 
-- for each account 
create unique index only_one_current_balance 
   on dates (account_id)
   where is_current_balance;
```

Before you change a row in `dates` to be the "current one", you need to reset the existing one to `false`.

---

Unrelated, but:

With modern Postgres versions it's [recommended](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) to use `identity` columns instead of `serial`

Comment: That is exceptionally good answer, thank you! But isn't it way more efficient to keep reference to actual date in account than searching for it every time? Or constraint also keeps reference to date record with current_balance?

Comment: Searching the current balance is efficient as it will be done through a unique index, so it's nearly constant in time regardless of the size of the table.